# Swapping strings

Tags: c, string

Have written a routine to swap strings , the first routine fails where as the second routine correctly swaps . Need to know the reason for the same they seem to do the same thing not sure why the second one works perfectly not the first .

**First Method**

```
void swap(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  char *temp = str1;
  str1 = str2;
  str2 = temp;
}
```

**Second Method**

```
void swap(char **str1, char **str2)
{
  char *temp = *str1;
  *str1 = *str2;
  *str2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: C is pass by value. You want to read about the *Dereferencing*-operator.

Comment: Another approach would be to compile the two snippets and then debug the code using a debugger stepping through the code inspecting all relevant variables to the what is *really* going on.

Comment: @alk : that would crash for sure

Comment: @alk Might be a bad example since string literal "hello" isn't of type `char**`. Creating local pointers to string literals and then swapping them of course works fine. However writing to data/read only segment won't work which I guess is what you're really after :)

Comment: Why there's a downvote for the question ?

Comment: @SanthoshPai I guess because it's been asked numerous times before and they probably thought you should use the search function first hehe.

Comment: @Jite: Hu, temp brain lapse .. yes. thank you. Cleaning up ...

Comment: In a programming language special symbols like `*` are not just for decoration, but have a meaning. Why do you expect `*` to have the same implications like `*`? (Note: I don't talk about comments!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: The first function gets copies of the pointers and you just modify these copies, not what the original pointer actually points too.

Longer: The second function takes gets pointer-to-pointer "copies" that which in turn (presumably) containts the addresses to the original location of your real pointers. In that function you change what the original pointers point to.

If we compare a pointer to an int, an int variable has an address in memory, and the value at that memory address is the number that the int contains. `int a = 4`, `a` has an adress at which the number `4` is stored. Same goes for pointers. A pointer say `char *b = "cde"`, `b` has an address where it's value is stored. A pointer contains the "value" that is another address, in this case the address to where the string "cde" is stored.

So what happens in your first function is that you send the value of `str1` or `str2`, not the address to `str1`/`str2` themselves. If you send the address of str1/str2 as in the second example, you are sending a `pointer-to-pointer` (`char**`) and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters you pass to a function are always passed by value in C, which means changes you make *to the parameters themselves* in the function aren't reflected outside the function.  In the first method, changing `str2` inside the function doesn't change `str2` outside the function.  In the second method, with `**str2`, the extra `*` is actually reaching outside the function to change what `str2` points to (and the same for `str1`).  Therefore, the changes are visible outside the function.